# Android Studio Error : Cause: invalid type code: 19

Tags: android, android-studio

I had update my Android Studio from 3.5.2 to 4.0.1 days ago and it's ok to read projects from github, but when I try to build a new project it went wrong, just throw the error :

> Cause:invalid type code:19 or Cause:invalid type code:FE

and in the idea.log shows this:
[image]

I have spend one day for it but still have no idea to resolve it

Comment: Can you share more details on the project this happens with? Or does it happen with every project?

Comment: it happen with every project which is created after the update, and I have no idea if the update cause the problem or something else

Comment: Have you tried resetting your IDE settings? (After doing a backup)

Comment: noop,but i have not change any setting after update the idea, will it case some probleam?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it, the problem was caused by the incorrect environment of JDK, I used JDK14 before and after I change it to JDK8, the problem have resolved